# /codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: 4: sonar-scanner: not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I have to integrate sonarclaud with codebuild and I am getting this error
/codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: 4: sonar-scanner: not found
while build the project.

Comment: It would help to know which docker image you have configured codebuild to use